# ¿Cómo evitar que variable guarde todos los resultados previos en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un script que descarga desde el servidor un archivo en formato xml invocado por un botón en una columna de opciones en una datatable y lo guarda en un objeto blob para posteriormente insertarlo en el html a través del paquete simpleXML, adicional habilito un botón que permite descargar dicho archivo xml a través de la función  `window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);`, todo esto funciona perfectamente al trabajar con el primer archivo, sin embargo cuando solicito otro archivo xml el script funciona al ver el contenido pero al dar clic en el botón descargar se vuelve a descarga el primer archivo solicitado junto con el nuevo archivo solicitado y así de forma recursiva

```
<button type="button" id="btndownload" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" style="display:none;">Descargar</button>

$.ajax({
        url: "/returnfiles",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response) {
            $('#id_file').html('');
            name = data.UUID+'xml'
            document.getElementById("id_file").innerHTML="";
            var xmlText = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(response);
            var blob = new Blob([xmlText], {type: "application/xml"});
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            descargarfile(url, name);
            closemodal(url);
            $("#id_file").simpleXML({ xmlString:xmlText });
            $("#btndownload").show();
            $('#visor').modal('show');
          },
        error: function(response) {$('#msg').html(response.message)
                                   // display error response
                                   }
    });


function descargarfile(url, name){
$('#btndownload').on('click', function() {
    console.log(url);
    event.preventDefault();
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.download = name;
    link.click();
});}

function closemodal(url){
$('#close_modal').on('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
});}
```

He intentado eliminar el contenido de la variable `url` sin exito y al ver el resultado del `console.log(url)` este muestra que los datos de la variable `url` se acumulan en la función `descargarfile`.

Espero me puedan apoyar en indicarme como puedo modificar mi script para que solo me descargue el archivo que se solicita en la petición.

Comment: El problema puede estar en que la función `descargarfile` añade un nuevo evento "click" cada que se llama... por eso la segunda vez que lo ejecutas ya tiene 2 eventos y la tercera 3 eventos... la solucion puede estar en usar la funcion [one](https://api.jquery.com/one/): `$('#btndownload').one('click', function() {` para asegurarse que ese evento solo se ejecutará una vez

Comment: Excelente es justo lo que necesitaba, gracias